Update / create FPT using API
Is it possible to update / create FPT (fixed product tax) for a Magento 2 product using the REST API?
I have not been able to find anything about it.
Current way to administrate in bulk is either product by product in admin or to query direct into database.
Reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-admin/stores-sales/site-store/taxes/fixed-product-tax

Did you have a custom FPT attribute created in products?

please check the below link hope it will be useful for you. : https://www.hulkapps.com/blogs/ecommerce-hub/how-to-update-fixed-product-tax-fpt-for-magento-2-products-using-rest-api
